# Get text from edit text to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a main activity and a result and a result2.....
I want to go to result from activity and then to result2 from result 1 .
but my codes dont seem to work pls help !

this is mainactivity ////////

```
public class MainActivity extends SampleActivityBase {

// Whether the Log Fragment is currently shown
private boolean mLogShown;
public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

EditText cardnumber;
TextView foodorders;
Button btnorder;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 10;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cardnumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.card_account_field);
    cardnumber.setText(AccountStorage.GetAccount(getBaseContext()));
    cardnumber.addTextChangedListener(new AccountUpdater());
    foodorders = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodordershow);
    btnorder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonorder);


    btnorder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String strcardnumber = cardnumber.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, activityresult1.class);
            intent.putExtra("Card Number:", strcardnumber);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

}

private class AccountUpdater implements TextWatcher {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // Not implemented.
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // Not implemented.
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String account = s.toString();
        AccountStorage.SetAccount(getBaseContext(), account);
    }
```

this is the result 1

```
  public class activityresult1 extends Activity {


EditText frq, fnq, foodordershow;
Button suborder;
TextView noodlequantity, ricequantity;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 10;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activityresult2);

    fnq = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fnq);
    frq = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.frq);
    noodlequantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noodlequantity);
    ricequantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ricequantity);
    suborder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.suborder);


    suborder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String strnoodlequantity = noodlequantity.getText().toString();
            String strricequantity = ricequantity.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activityresult2.class);
            intent.putExtra("Noodle quantity", strnoodlequantity);
            intent.putExtra("Rice quantity", strricequantity);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (data.hasExtra("Food Ordered:")) {
            String result = data.getExtras().getString("Food Ordered:");
            if (result != null && result.length() > 0) {
                foodordershow.setText("Food Ordered: " + result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and lastly result 2

```
 public class activityresult2 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activityresult1);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String strfnq = extras.getString("Noodle Quantity");
    String strfrq = extras.getString("Rice Quantity");
    TextView foodorders = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodordershow);
    foodorders.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("Quantity"));

    foodorders = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodordershow);
    foodorders.setText("Welcome, " + strfnq + " + strfrq + ");
    finish();


}
```

Comment: what do you mean by this line "I want to go to result from activity and then to result2 from result 1 . but my codes dont seem to work pls help !"

Comment: what is javascript tag doing in this question??

Comment: What is REQUEST_CODE and why are you using it.?

Comment: coz this is activity .JAVA ? @VivekMishra

Comment: @AmitRanjan i have this codes that i want it to work , i copied most from my teacher but she want me to make the buttons work . so after putting all the buttons  like                                                          .......................................                                         suborder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)  ...............................................................the programme dosnt work and i dont know why

Comment: you use intent.putExtra("Noodle quantity", strnoodlequantity);to send data but you use Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();to catch data,        that is difference thing.

Comment: There is a big difference between Java and JavaScript

Comment: @malavshah i didnt know . so yeah thanks

Comment: @Hsieh so what should i write because i am a total beginner and i just started this android studio lesson for 1week

Comment: hi NJ can u message me at wenhan999@hotmail.com  i got some question that i want to ask you but i dont know how to explain but i can sent u my codes. pls drop me a message via email thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maybe you can try to use Bundle to package the data

mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends SampleActivityBase {

// Whether the Log Fragment is currently shown
private boolean mLogShown;
public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

EditText cardnumber;
TextView foodorders;
Button btnorder;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 10;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cardnumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.card_account_field);
    cardnumber.setText(AccountStorage.GetAccount(getBaseContext()));
    cardnumber.addTextChangedListener(new AccountUpdater());
    foodorders = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodordershow);
    btnorder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonorder);


    btnorder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String strcardnumber = cardnumber.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, activityresult1.class);
            intent.putExtra("Card Number:", strcardnumber);
            //if you need to let activityresult1 back to MainActivity with data, you can use startActivityForResult, if not just use startActivity(intent).
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

}

private class AccountUpdater implements TextWatcher {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // Not implemented.
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // Not implemented.
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String account = s.toString();
        AccountStorage.SetAccount(getBaseContext(), account);
    }
```

this is the result 1

```
public class activityresult1 extends Activity {


EditText frq, fnq, foodordershow;
Button suborder;
TextView noodlequantity, ricequantity;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 10;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activityresult2);

    fnq = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fnq);
    frq = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.frq);
    noodlequantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noodlequantity);
    ricequantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ricequantity);
    suborder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.suborder);


    suborder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String strnoodlequantity = noodlequantity.getText().toString();
            String strricequantity = ricequantity.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activityresult2.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("Noodle quantity", strnoodlequantity);
            bundle.putString("Rice quantity", strricequantity);
            //intent.putExtra("Noodle quantity", strnoodlequantity);
            //intent.putExtra("Rice quantity", strricequantity);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (data.hasExtra("Food Ordered:")) {
            String result = data.getExtras().getString("Food Ordered:");
            if (result != null && result.length() > 0) {
                foodordershow.setText("Food Ordered: " + result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and lastly result 2

```
public class activityresult2 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activityresult1);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String strfnq = extras.getString("Noodle Quantity");
    String strfrq = extras.getString("Rice Quantity");
    TextView foodorders = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodordershow);
    foodorders.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("Quantity"));

    foodorders = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodordershow);
    foodorders.setText("Welcome, " + strfnq + " + strfrq + ");
    //finish();


}
```

Comment: i found my problem . is that after the activity main my button cannot submit and transfer me to the result 1 page .

Comment: sorry I don't know what you mean, but  after you call startActivity(intent);or startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE); , it will transfer you to another activity

Comment: Is it  cool if you can email me and i give u my folder so u can see my problem ? wenhan999@hotmail.com